# How to convert org.joda.time.DateTime to com.mindfusion.common.DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have problem with a java project.

I have to convert a `String` to `com.mindfusion.common.DateTime`, all I managed to do is to convert it to `org.joda.time.DateTime` using the following code:

```
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
org.joda.time.DateTime d2 = formatter.parseDateTime("2/7/2016 12:00:00");
```

I want to use it like that:

```
Appointment a = new Appointment();
a.setStartTime(d2);
```

but `setStartTime()` needs `com.mindfusion.common.DateTime`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to call the constructor specifying all the various fields:

```
a.setStartTime(new com.mindfusion.common.DateTime(
    d2.getYear(), d2.getMonthOfYear(), d2.getDayOfMonth(),
    d2.getHourOfDay(), d2.getMinuteOfHour(), d2.getSecondOfMinute());
```

Note that it doesn't appear to have any time zone support, which is somewhat worrying...

Comment: you are right i have to add also timezone (I want it GMT)

Comment: I am getting errors on every `.get()` exept `.getYear()`

Comment: @taleporos: Edited the getters... but I don't know what you mean by "I have to add also time zone" - the point is the `mindfusion` version doesn't *have* a time zone, as far as I can see. (For a "sophisticated" date/time API it looks pretty poor to me...)

Comment: `System.out.println(d2);` prints the following: `2016-07-02T12:00:00.000+03:00`

Comment: I was curious about that `T` between date and time

Comment: @taleporos: Wow, I'm not sure how I was meant to know that... that's just ISO-8601 formatting.

Comment: @taleporos For UTC, adjust the DateTime object by specifying a UTC time zone, then extract the new DateTime object’s elements as shown in this Answer: `DateTime d2Utc = d2.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );`